# Changing hover text value in plotly

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly-python

I have plotted a grouped bar plot using the below code:

```
col1 = {
        'abc': '#323233',
        'xyz': '#C92735',
        }
fig = px.bar(df, x="id", y="Total", color="sys_type", barmode="group",
               color_discrete_map=col1)
fig.layout = go.Layout(
        title=go.layout.Title(text="Total value for each id", x=0.5),
        xaxis_title="Id",
        yaxis_title="Total Value"
    )
fig.show()
```

The y axis on graph is represented in terms of thousands, such as 35k, 45k but when I hover over the graph, the same value is represented in decimal form (41.07k). How can I change this hover value to 41070 instead of 41.07k?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a text value in .bar method

```
col1 = {
        'abc': '#323233',
        'xyz': '#C92735',
        }

def convert(value):
    value /= 1000
    return str(round(value, 2))+”k”
 
fig = px.bar(df, x="id",text=[convert(_) for _ in df[‘x’].values.tolist()] y="Total", color="sys_type", barmode="group",
               color_discrete_map=col1)
fig.layout = go.Layout(
        title=go.layout.Title(text="Total value for each id", x=0.5),
        xaxis_title="Id",
        yaxis_title="Total Value"
    )
fig.show()
```